# Hibernate Many-Many relationship with cascade delete

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have a requirement to implement role-right based authentication. The scenario is like,

**A role has multiple/many rights.
In opposite,
A right can be assigned to multiple role(s).**

So, here team has designed three tables names as,

1) Role (Columns: roleId,name,desc)

2) Right (Columns : rightId,name,desc)

3) RoleRightAssociation (Columns : roleId,rightId,assignedDate,assignedBy)

The third table is storing the data like,

**Right 'A' was assigned to Role 'B' by the user 'X' on a particular date.**

**UseCase** is,
 When I delete a Role all the entries from RoleRightAssociation corresponding to that Role must be deleted (Delete Cascade). But Not from a Right table.

I've created three entities for this and given the relations like,
Role:

```
 @OneToMany(mappedBy="roleRoghtId.roleId",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<RoleRight> roleRightsList=new ArrayList<RoleRight>();
```

Right:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="roleRoghtId.rightId",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
   private List<RoleRight> roleRightsList;
```

RoleRightAssociation:

```
     @Entity
     @Table(name = "RoleRight")
     @AssociationOverrides({ 
     @AssociationOverride(name = "roleRoghtId.roleId",joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "roleId")),
     @AssociationOverride(name = "roleRoghtId.rightId",joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "rightId")) })
public class RoleRightAssociation {
...
   @EmbeddedId
    private PrimaryKeyRoleRight roleRoghtId=new PrimaryKeyRoleRight();

...
}
```

PrimaryKeyRoleRight :

```
 @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Role roleId;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Right rightId;
```

I am not able to satisfy the given use case.
What relations do I need to apply in respected JPA entities?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Cascade.ALL does not include `delete Orphan`.

You have to add `orphanRemoval = true` to your `roleRightsList` in `Role` entity